# Closed form of $\int_0^1 \tan(\gamma\sqrt{1-x^2}) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics, closed-form

Some context: I'm studying the problem of nonperturbative pair creation from strong fields in quantum electrodynamics. For certain time dependent electric fields I can get some information about the qualitative behavior from integrals of the form
$$ \tilde{h}(\gamma) = \int_0^1 h(\gamma\sqrt{1-x^2}) dx, $$
where $h$ depends on the field profile and $\gamma$ is something like an inverse timescale (if $h$ has any poles, $\gamma$ is always restricted to an appropriate region).

For $h=\sinh$, $h=\tanh^{-1}$ and $h=\mathrm{erfi}$ (the imaginary error function) Mathematica provides closed form solutions, but not for $h=\tan$, which I am greatly interested in.

The only idea I had was expressing $h$ using its Taylor series and integrating term by term, which I can do because

$$ \int_0^1 \gamma^n (1-x^2)^{n/2} dx = \gamma^n  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\Gamma(1+n/2)}{\Gamma(3/2 + n/2)}, $$

and then sum up the resulting series. This again works for the other functions mentioned above, but not for the tangent.

Any ideas how to get a closed form result of the integral for $h=\tan$?

**Edit:**
The results Mathematica is able to compute are:
$$ \text{for } h = \sinh: \quad\tilde{h}(\gamma) = \frac{\pi}{2} I_1(\gamma ), $$
$$ \text{for } h = \tanh^{-1}: \quad\tilde{h}(\gamma) = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\gamma ^2}}{ \gamma }, $$
$$ \text{for } h = \mathrm{erfi}: \quad\tilde{h}(\gamma) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi }\gamma}{2}  e^{\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}}  \left(I_0\left(\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}\right)-I_1\left(\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}\right)\right). $$

Comment: Did you try the substitution $y=\gamma \sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Comment: Or better probably $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: Have YOU tried it? If you had, you would have noticed that it only complicates the integral.

Comment: @AlexM., I did. And how do you know it complicates the integral, unless you solved it already? Neater form doesn't mean an easier solution

Comment: @AlexM., I don't understand your reaction at all. If the integral contains some kind non-algebraic function ($\tan$ in this case), the most common way is to make the argument of this function as simple as possible

Comment: @You'reInMyEye yeah I did, actually that is the way it comes up in the calculation, I chose this form because I thought it looked neater... It does not get me any further though.

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: ...which moves the "difficult part" somewhere else in the new integral. The idea is to suggest approaches only if you have tried them and they have succeded. Otherwise, every reader of this question could post a comment with some useless "hint".

Comment: can you determine the residue at infinity of the function $\frac{\tan(\gamma x)x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$(seems to be though)? if yes, i think i know a way

Comment: @tired the leading term in an expansion around $\infty$ of this function is $-\text{i}\times \tan(\gamma x)$.

Comment: @tired: Isn't $\infty$ an essential singularity for that fraction, in which case that residue does not exist? (Essentially, $\tan$ has no limit towards $\infty$.)

Comment: I am not able to understand what is $gamma$ here. Can you provide a closed form for other profiles as in Mathematica

Comment: @AlexM. that's true, but it might be possible to calculate the residue (at least sometimes )anyway: http://wwwteor.mi.infn.it/~molinari/METODI/Residue.pdf

Comment: @AmanRajput $\gamma$ is just a parameter $>0$ (and for $\tan$ $\gamma<\pi/2$). I'll add the results for the other profiles in a moment.

Comment: Don't know if it may be useful, but your integral can be also rewritten as $$
\frac{1}{2\gamma}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\frac{1}{2} \pi  \left(\pmb{L}_{-1}(w)+I_1(w)\right)-1}{\sinh \left(\frac{\pi  w}{2 \gamma }\right)} \, dw
$$, where $\pmb{L}$ is a Struve function and $I_1$ a Bessel function.

Comment: Okay a parameter.  Got it

Comment: You should change the parameter with other symbol because at first glance it looks euler mascheroni constant≈-0.577

Comment: If it helps, it can be also written as $$\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_1(2na)$$

Comment: - EDIT to @Machinato (myself), $n$ should start from $0$, not $1$

Comment: Another two representations $\frac{\pi}{\gamma}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\gamma^2}{\pi^2 n^2}}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4\gamma^2}{\pi^2 n^2}}}\right)$ and $\frac{\pi}{\gamma}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1/2)_n}{n!}(4^n-1)\zeta(2n)({\gamma}/{\pi})^{2n}$, where  $0<|\gamma|<\pi/2$

Comment: @Machinato: Where should $\gamma$ be in your formula? Is it $a$?

Comment: @AlexM. yeah, with $a=\gamma$ it fits a numerical evaluation of the integral! How did you get to this expression Machinato ? It's not quite as useful as a simple closed expression, but easy enough to evaluate up to some $N$ as an approximation! The same for your series, Nemo!

Comment: @Machinato, with $n$ starting from zero you also need a global $-1$, one could also change $n$ to $n-1$ in the argument of $J_1$ instead!

Comment: @AlexM. Exactly (and apologize to not responding few hours due to time zone difference), $a=\gamma$

Comment: @cnschn The derivation is straighf., however, not obvious at first glance, so I will try reverse approach instead of direct : it begins with the formulae: (for natural $\nu$)
$$J_\nu(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{it\nu-ix\sin t}dt$$
Hence
$$\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_1(2na)
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{it-2ian\sin t}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}}{1+e^{-2ia\sin t}}dt$$
Sum is real, taking the real part :
$$S=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(t+a\sin t)}{4\cos(a\sin t)}dt
=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin t \sin(a\sin t)}{4\cos(a\sin t)}dt$$
Same integral

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find a nice closed form in the case of $I(\gamma)=\int_0^1 \tan(\gamma\sqrt{1-x^2}) dx$.

I have managed to integrate the series expansion for $\tan(\gamma\sqrt{1-x^2})$ term by term using mathematica. Due to the limits used a lot of the resultant terms are zero. The only term that is non-zero is a term involving $\arcsin(x)$.  The result I find is similar in form to @nemo's second result, although nemo uses the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) in the form $\frac{(1/2)_n}{n!}$ which differs from my formulation as it alternates in sign. Assuming I have calculated it correctly, nemo's second result does not agree numerically with the original integral or my result.

My result is

$$I(\gamma)=\frac{\pi}{\gamma}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(2^{2k}-1\right)\zeta(2k)\left(\frac{\gamma}{\pi} \right)^{2k}\prod_{j=1}^k\left(\frac{2j-1}{2j}\right),$$

which is different to any of the results given above in the comments.

Substituting for $\zeta(2k)$ using $\zeta(2k)=\frac{(2\pi)^{2k}}{2(2k)!}|B_{2k}|$ and for the product using the identity $\prod_{j=1}^k\left(\frac{2j-1}{2j}\right)=\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2} =\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\binom{2k}{k}$  gives

$$I(\gamma)=\frac{\pi}{2\gamma}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2^{2k}-1)\;|B_{2k}|\;{\gamma}^{2k}}{(2k)!} \binom{2k}{k}.$$

The rational product $\prod_{j=1}^k\left(\frac{2j-1}{2j}\right)$ could also be written in terms of the ratio of two gamma functions (after using the substitution $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{x}$). This is the one Mathematica likes to use.

$$\prod_{j=1}^k\left(\frac{2j-1}{2j}\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \;\Gamma (k+1)}.$$

This is interesting as it appears the series for $I(\gamma)$ is a hybrid between two different classes of standard series (e.g. a sort of hybrid between $\tan x$ or $\log \cos x$ involving Bernoulli numbers and $\arcsin x$ involving $\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\binom{2k}{k}$).